# how to append into id javascript variable using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am doing like this

```
<script>
 $(document).on("click", ".modal-trigger", function () {
 var myBookId = $(this).data('id');
 var name = $(this).data('name');
 var name1 = $(this).data('name1');
 var lastname = $(this).data('lastname');
 var lastname1 = $(this).data('lastname1');
 var rollno = $(this).data('rollno');
 var rollno1 = $(this).data('rollno1');
 var msisdn = $(this).data('msisdn');
 var msisdn1 = $(this).data('msisdn1');
 var cnic = $(this).data('cnic');
 var cnic1 = $(this).data('cnic1');
 var campus = $(this).data('campus');
  var campus1 = $(this).data('campus1');
 var hear = $(this).data('hear');
 var hear1 = $(this).data('hear1');
  var qualified = $(this).data('qualified');
  var qualified1 = $(this).data('qualified1');
 $(".modal-content #applicantid").val( myBookId );
 var appli_name = $("#appli_name").val(name);
  $("#appli_name1").val(name1);
 $("#appli_lastname").val(lastname);
 $("#appli_lastname1").val(lastname1);
 $("#appli_rollno").val(rollno);
 $("#appli_rollno1").val(rollno1);
 $("#appli_msisdn").val(msisdn);
  $("#appli_msisdn1").val(msisdn1);
 $("#appli_cnic").val(cnic);
  $("#appli_cnic1").val(cnic1);
 $("#appli_campus").val(campus);
 $("#appli_campus1").val(campus1);
 $("#appli_hear").val(hear);
 $("#appli_hear1").val(hear1);
  $("#appli_qualified").val(qualified);
 $("#appli_qualified1").val(qualified1);
   $("#applicant_info").append("<label>Name:</label>"+ "<label>"+appli_name+"</label>");
 });
  </script>
```

But its showing like this way **Name:[object Object]**

I am opening a modal and show the data on modal using javascript

```
<a href="#modal2" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php echo $CRow['id'];?>" data-name="<?php echo $CRow['name'];?>"  data-msisdn="<?php echo $CRow['msisdn'];?>" data-cnic="<?php echo $CRow['cnic'];?>" data-campus="<?php echo $CamRow[0];?>" data-rollno="<?php echo $CRow['rollno'];?>" data-hear="<?php echo $HearRow[0];?>" data-qualified="<?php echo $CRow['qualification'];?>" class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light yellow modal-trigger" title="Test">
```

Append to this div

```
<div id="applicant_info">
</div>
```

How to append this javascript variable into this id

Comment: Can you please add your HTML code?

Comment: which part of html??

Comment: What is `this` referring to in `$(this).data('name');`???

Comment: The relevant HTML - the HTML we need to solve your problem

Comment: Also add the complete JavaScript code - there are some things we need to know to be able to solve your problem

Comment: please check my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a similar code:

```js
$('body').on('click', '#btnn', function() {
  var name = $(this).data('name');
  var appli_name = $("#appli_name").val(name);
  $("#applicant_info").append("<label>Name:</label>" + "<label>" + name + "</label>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-name="name" id="btnn">button</button>
<input id="appli_name" value="" />
<div id="applicant_info"></div>
```

The mistake that you have did is that you use `appli_name` to append in some other place & this is not a variable its actually a object.

you can use directly the variable `name` on appending as I did.

```
var appli_name = $("#appli_name").val(name); // its a object
```

Comment: Thanks for supporting